# How to restrict your content in only one page in pdf using itext?

Tags: itext, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate pdf using itext libs and I want to prevent page break. I want all my content in single page pdf only. How to achieve this?

Comment: Make the page size larger enough for your content fitting on a single page.

Comment: Is that not like saying I would like to drive across the country but never more than 10 miles? The content is the content. You can set page dimensions within the limits of PDF but your question is not answerable. You cannot format the entire encyclopedia in one page.

Comment: Hi, please share your code so far and specify the version you are using